# Understanding "divides" notation, aka "|", in sigma notation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, notation

[image: Sigma notation in question]

In the picture above, there is a $d \mid (k,n)$ under the sigma notation. I know this means that $d$ has to divide the highest common factor of $k$ and $n$, but I would like to further understand how the notation applies to the sigma above it. I understand the other symbols in the expression.

Does this mean I find the value of the expression next to the sigma for each $d$ that divides the highest common factor of $k$ and $n$, then sum all of these values?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is what it means.

Basically, any time there is an expression below $\sum$ (apart from the standard $\sum_{i = 0}^n$ or similar) that might or might not be true, then it's taken to mean "Take whatever comes after in every case where the expression is true and sum them all together".

For instance, next to your example, variations on the notation
$$
\sum_{0\leq i,j \leq n}
$$
are probably most common, and this one means "evaluate whatever comes after once for each pair of $i$ and $j$ with $0\leq i\leq n$ and $0\leq j \leq n$, and sum them all together"